# Not all commands work with exec/shell_exec

Tags: php

I have an apache2 server on a Raspberry Pi 4.

All the php web-pages are in `/var/www/html`.

I have the following **working** `shell_exec` in one php file:

```
if(isset($_POST['restart_device'])) {
    shell_exec("sudo /var/www/html/restart_device.sh");
    header("Location: /");
    die();
}
```

and this **not working** `shell_exec` in another php file:

```
$make_exe = "sudo chmod +x $uploadFileDir"."$fileName";
shell_exec($make_exe);
```

Echoing `$make_exe` returns `sudo chmod +x /var/www/html/uploads/MP_Display`.

I have added `www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /var/www/html/` in `/etc/sudoers.tmp` using `sudo visudo`.

Why is one working and the other one does not ?

I have tried using:

```
exec($make_exe, $full, $status);
if($status != 0) {
    echo "<br>Something went wrong<br>";
} else {
    echo "<br>$response<br>";
}
```

and it always returns `Something went wrong`.

## EDIT:

`chmod` works without `sudo`. Executing a binary file works without `sudo`. But moving a file doesn't work at all !

I have tried running the command with exec:

```
$move_command = "sudo mv $uploadFileDir.$fileName /var/www/html/4panel/";
exec($move_command, $full_1, $status);
var_dump($full_1);
if($status !=0 ) { } else {}
```

This returns `array(0) { }` and it doesn't work.

Then I have tried with a shell script:

```
mv /var/www/html/uploads/MP_Display /var/www/html/4panel/
```

that I ran from php:

```
shell_exec("sudo /var/www/html/rmv_fl.sh")
```

I know that running a shell script from php works `shell_exec("sudo /var/www/html/restart_device.sh");`

Why isn't `mv` working at all ?

Comment: To edit the sudoers file, you should use the `visudo` command. After editing verify it with `visudo -c`. It can be catastrophic if you make a typo there.

Comment: @Daan I did edit it with `sudo visudo`. Also, running `sudo visudo -c`  returns all OK.

Comment: `sudoers.tmp` is the lock file. What is in your /etc/sudoers file?

Comment: Define "not working". What's the output/return value of the command?

Comment: *"sudo chmod"* -- you're doing something terribly wrong. Why do you need `sudo` for this?

Comment: @axiac www-data probably isn't the owner of file `MP_Display`.

Comment: @Daan Running `sudo visudo` opens `/etc/sudoers.tmp`. Also, in `/etc/sudoers` is the same thing as in `/etc/sudoers.tmp`.

Comment: @deceze It returns nothing.

Comment: @axiac why ? I need sudo even in command line for chmod, not just in `shell_exec`

Comment: Have you tried outputting `$full`…?

Comment: @Daan www-data is actually the owner of `MP_Display` : `-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 1508920 Oct  2 13:26 MP_Display`

Comment: @deceze You are talking about `exec`. I was talking about `shell_exec`

Comment: If you code needs `sudo` to `chmod` the file, how does it create the file in that directory?

Comment: @GeorgicaFaraFrica In that case you do not need sudo to `chmod`!

Comment: Anyway, the base idea is that when you use `sudo` to do non-admin tasks you are on the wrong path. A path that leads to using `sudo` more and more until you start wondering why don't you use the `root` account instead. And this is exactly what the `sudo` command tries to avoid. Its purpose is to allow the regular users do **some** admin tasks. Restarting a service is such a task but `chmod` is not.

Comment: @deceze `exec($make_exe, $full, $status);
echo implode(PHP_EOL, $full);` output nothing.

Comment: Ok, great. The commands work without `sudo`. Even executing it works without `sudo`. Why ? Now I will try to use another command that will require to delete a file owned by root and replace it with `MP_Display`. This will most definitely need `sudo, right ?

Comment: `$move_command = "mv $uploadFileDir.$fileName /var/www/html/4panel/ ";` executing this doesn't work.

Comment: `$move_command = "sudo mv $uploadFileDir.$fileName /var/www/html/4panel/ ";` and `exec($move_command, $full_1, $status);` return `array(0) { }` with `var_dump($full_1);`

Comment: Impersonating www-data and doing `mv /var/www/html/uploads/Metrici_MP_Display /var/www/html/4panel/` works. Why can't it be done from `exec` ?

Answer (score 0):

Other than looking very scary from a security point of view, there is nothing wrong with the code you posted.

To debug issues with running these commands, impersonate the web server user (`www-data`). That way you can run all these commands as if you were the PHP script and see what errors they might be causing.

To do this open a terminal in your Raspberry Pi and run `sudo su www-data -s /bin/bash`. Subsequent commands will be run as `www-data` (try there `sudo /var/www/html/restart_device.sh`, etc.)

Note that a directory in sudoers allows for execution of files in THAT directory *only*. From man sudoers (emphasis mine):

> A directory is a fully qualified path name
>        ending in a ‘/’.  When you specify a directory in a Cmnd_List, the user will be able to run any file within that directory (but **not
>        in any sub-directories** therein).

Comment: Why is it `very scary` ? How can I do it to be less scary ?

Comment: Apparently, you are running an uploaded script as root. Whatever is on that script will be executed, including any modifications to the system, passwords, etc. The "safe" way would really depend on what are you trying to archive as a whole.

Comment: But I am not running the php as root. `ps aux | grep httpd` returns pi as the owner of the server. Also, all php files inside `/var/www/html` are owned by pi:pi.

Comment: Impersonating www-data and doing `mv /var/www/html/uploads/Metrici_MP_Display /var/www/html/4panel/` works. Why can't it be done from `exec` ?

Comment: Try to determine what user does your PHP script runs with. `www-data` was a guess based on your sudoers, nothing will work if you are using different users.

Comment: That could be one of the problems. I have actually made shell scripts with the commands I need and I use `exec` and `shell_exec` to run them and get a return value. I have also changed the owner of `/var/www/html/` to `www-data:www-data`. These, combined, helped. Your `sudo su www-data -s /bin/bash` trick is also neat.

Comment: I have encountered one little issue: running a `sudo` command as www-data ask me to input www-data's password... which I have no clue where to get from

Comment: @GeorgicaFaraFrica check your sudoers file, if it's asking for password something is wrong there.

Comment: The only line that I have added in `sudoers` is `www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /var/www/html/scripts/`.

Comment: Is it better the way I did it ? I've moved all the scripts inside a folder, and I've given `sudo` permissions to `www-data` only on that folder. I have done this to restrict `www-data` from having `sudo` permissions on the whole `/var/www/html` directory. This should allow `www-data` to run the scripts as `sudo` and the scripts should be able to do things outside `/var/www/html/scripts`, correct ?

Comment: Correct. But `sudo mv` won't work since `/bin/mv` is not in that folder

Comment: Can we move this to a discussion. because I have a `mv` command inside a script that php runs with `sudo` ? I can't do that because I don't have enough points

Comment: Or how can I use `rm` and `mv` from a script that gets opened by PHP ?